# CKEditor violates layout borders in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

In Drupal 7 the CKEditor violates border of left column (where it should be) and penetrates into right column. Now, I can not resize it because when I resize borders of CKEditor by dragging resize button, the icons (image tabs) of CKEditor does not react and does not obey to this act and still remain in right column, although the very borders of editor are changed. 
In other words CKEditor icons not only violates borders of my site layout, but also it's own CKEditor borders. I should mention that this nuisance occurs only in my Chrome and Opera browsers, while, for example, in Firefox everything is ok. 
Version of CKEditor is 3.6.5. and by following some suggestions I tried to fix this problem by putting library of 3.6.6. version but no solution found. How can this be solved?

Comment: are you using ckeditor module?:

Comment: I installed CKEditor via wysiwyg module.

Comment: It works. Not very fancy skin, but it works:). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Install [CKEditor module](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) directly instead of use with wysiwyg module.

Comment: How does this solve the problem?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/ckeditor-violates-layout-borders-in-drupal-7/58289#comment63070_58032